# Set Woocommerce Product Attribute as a function of two other Product Attributes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, math, woocommerce, hook

I would like to generate a value for a WooCommerce  product attribute, in this case `spd` (Speed per Dollar). The `$speed` is static and the `price` changes from time to time. I would like the value of the `spd` attribute to change according to the `$price` automatically.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute', 'SPD');
function SPD(){
    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;
    $speed = $product->id , 'speed';
    $price = $product->price;
    $spd = ('$speed' / '$price');

    return $product->id , 'spd' = $spd
}
```

This is what i have so far, but It's been a while since I wooked with hooks and functions for wordpress. any help is appreciated.

Reposted from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238656/variable-attribute-values-with-woocommerce-products